How can I produce a second PDF in which the tooltip of each field is printed in the right hand margin opposite each field?
I have a PDF which contains many fields with tooltips. Each tooltip can be displayed by hovvering the pointer over the field in the usual way.
How can I produce a second PDF in which the tooltip of each field is printed in the right hand margin opposite each field?
I have looked at PDF X-Change Editor and Adobe Acrobat and Foxit but there doesn't seem to be a way to do it with any of those.

One of the problems with PDF tooltips is there is no set way they are to be seen. The word "Tooltip" does not appear in the PDF ISO Standard.
The ONE and ONLY use of the action "hover" is an option to

ToggleNoView
(PDF 1.5) If set, invert the interpretation of the NoView flag for annotation selection and mouse hovering, causing the annotation to be visible when the mouse pointer hovers over the annotation or when the annotation is selected.

Thus like many "Standards" woolly definitions can be interpreted as un-prescribed.
Here is tip in Edge

and another reader with and without content

Here is Acrobat

Here is a report where written in the PDF margins.
So this is Tracker Editor Comments report function.


The example you show uses PDF X-Change Editor (Tracker software). I have tried using the Comment - Summarise Comments button and, in the Summarise Comments pane, selecting all the comments boxes (Type, Page, Author, Subject, Date, Status) but the report generated does not show tooltips. In your example the word "Tooltip" appears but as far as I can see that is only because you are using a author name of "tooltip"!!!

@Nemo the READER writes the tooltip based on 3 sources either the Author of empty additions without comments OR a preview of the contents OR some scripted (usually AcroScript or Ecma JavaScript)  entries such as a menu of electrical components. but it is a mix of the pdf as carrier and the reader of behaviours. the real tooltip entries are not always seen in the PDF

Trying this out further it appears that what I thought was a tooltip is just part of the design of PDF X-Change Editor. Hovvering over the link using Adobe Acrobat, for example, does not produce the "tooltip" effect.

tooltips are the responsibility of PDF readers the standard suggests they show the content but does not say that it must be just the first line (some comments would be too big for a screen) nor does it say what to do when empty such as indicate who authored that one.
